# How can I get MiniZinc output to interpret escapes, instead of printing them literally?

Tags: formatting, minizinc

I'm trying to convert the tutorial's Australia program to use arrays.

I'm having trouble with the output, to wit:

```
% Coloring Australia using nc colors

int: nc = 3;  % number of colors
int: ns = 7;  % number of states
array[1..nc] of string:     colors = ["red", "green", "blue"]; 
array[1..ns] of string:     states = ["wa","nt","sa","q","nsw","v","t"]; 
array[1..ns] of var 1..ns:  indices = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

array[1..ns] of var 1..nc: color; % computed color for each state

% I want to use the name as a mnemonic for the index of the state
var int: wa=1; % I know of no alternative to the brute force method
var int: nt=2; var int: sa=3; var int: q=4;
var int: nsw=5; var int: v=6; var int: t=7;

constraint color[wa] != color[nt];  % abutting states
constraint color[wa] != color[sa];
constraint color[nt] != color[sa];
constraint color[nt] != color[q];
constraint color[sa] != color[q];
constraint color[sa] != color[nsw];
constraint color[sa] != color[v];
constraint color[q]  != color[nsw];
constraint color[v]  != color[nsw];

solve satisfy;

/*
  I want a loop to print it out like this:
"wa" = "blue"
"nt" = "green"
...  
*/

output [  
   show( ["\n\(states[j]) = \(colors[color[j]])" | j in indices])
];
/* prints

["\n\"wa\" = \"blue\"", "\n\"nt\" = \"green\"", "\n\"sa\" = \"red\"",     "\n\"q\" = \"blue\"", "\n\"nsw\" = \"green\"", "\n\"v\" = \"blue\"", "\n\"t\" = \"red\""]
*/
```

How can I get show to make the \n a new line, and not escape the quotes in the constants? Like perl double quotes instead of single quotes?

And/or is there any way to define the constants without the quotes? Like perl qw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a small mistake in your code: show is used to output a variable. So it is used like:

```
output["this is variable x:" ++ show(x)]
```

Note that `\(x)` is a shorthand for `"++show(x)++"`

The `output` statement itself will print the given array as a formatted string. This formatted string can contain escaped character as expected. The correct output statement for your model is thus:

```
output ["\n\(states[j]) = \(colors[color[j]])" | j in indices];
```